# Yakuake does not work on Red Hat 9.3 because of some KDE or Wayland libraries issues

Tags: rhel, kde, wayland, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to launch Yakuake on Red Hat 9.3 (Plow) and see following warning and errors:

```
$ yakuake
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
kf.windowsystem: Could not find any platform plugin
QDBusConnection: name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel' had owner '' but we thought it was ':1.97'
```

Yakuake window does not show at all, though it should after hitting F12. I see only console output.

Version info:

```
$ dnf info yakuake
...
Name         : yakuake
Version      : 23.04.3
...
```

Could anybody help with fixing this issue? Tried to google it, but failed to found solution. Tried to set env variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` and relaunch desktop session - same output.